# How to change three-tap behaviour from cortana to middle click?

Tags: touchpad, windows-10, cortana

I've just updated my Samsung NP730U to Windows 10.

The touchpad driver (Elan Smart-Pad) updated it's driver too, and now the only option for Three-Finger-Tap is invoking Cortana.

I'd much rather have it work as before, ie. emulate middle click. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open regedit.exe
2. Navigate to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER > SOFTWARE > Elantech > SmartPad`
3. Modify the value of `Tap_Two_Finger_Enable` to `1`
4. Modify the value of `Tap_Two_Finger` to `2`
5. Reboot

Comment: Indeed this is what I had configured with Windows 8 on my ASUS UX31A.  Now in Windows 10, ASUS Smart Gesture (Version V4.0.5) seems to disable this registry setting -- three-finger tap always opens Cortana?

Comment: @Hugues I can only confirm that this method works on my own computer: Samsung NP900X3C, running Windows 10, running an ELAN driver v11.7.33.1 (which does indeed have the Cortana option available).
I successfully changed the three finger tap to middle click using the above method (obviously changing `Tap_Three_Finger` instead).
It is worth noting that the registry value for Cortana is setting `Tap_Three_Finger` to `0x1a` (at least for Samsung models). @Hugues, does the registry reset it to this value upon a restart?

Comment: My Asus laptop has ELAN Touchpad 11.15.0.14_X64, which came in through Windows Update I think.  Unfortunately I don't (yet) see any web sites with other choices for ELAN drivers for Windows 10. `Tap_Three_Finger` is still `2` as I set it, even after reboot.  Apparently it is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after v19 of the Synaptics/Dell touchpad driver got installed while upgrading. Uninstalling that, and with a bit of googling, finding the older v18 driver solved it for me.